# How to validate data based on first row data and delete invalid ones

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE #mappingInfo(id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), cntID INT, intCntId INT, conID INT)    
INSERT INTO #mappingInfo VALUES 
(921, 111, 30),
(921, 111, NULL),
(921, NUll, NULL),
(921, NULL, 40),
(921, 111, 50),
(922, NULL, 40),
(922, 111, 50),
(922, NULL, 60)
```

From the above table, columns `intCntId` and `conID` are option but if we setup data for the calculation in these two columns then all the other data should be in same form as first. I mean the first row will always be valid as in example below:

```
intCntId    conID
NULL        10

Other setup Can be 
NULL        20
NULL        30

Can't be
NULL        NULL
20          NULL
30          30
```

If first data of that column is either `NULL` or `NOT NULL` the rest of setup data shoul be same but it can be defined with different value.

In the above table `FIRST` and `LAST` row is valid and I have to either `pick` only valid data OR `delete` invalid ones.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**Note: I have updated the question as it is to be done by each cntID wise. So I have added more records in sample table**

Comment: We can use `ID` where as the minimum `ID` of each `cntID` is the first and valid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here another approach. The cte might need some additional modification - e.g. a "FIRST_VALUE OVER" or a "WHERE ID = (SELECT min(ID)...)". However, quite "light weight", the solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), cntID INT, intCntId INT, conID INT)    
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(921, 111, 30),
(921, 111, NULL),
(921, NUll, NULL),
(921, NULL, 40),
(921, 111, 50),
(922, NULL, 40),
(922, 111, 50),
(922, NULL, 60);

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT cntID
        ,CASE WHEN intCntId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS intCntId
        ,CASE WHEN conID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS conID
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cntID ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM @t
)
SELECT *
  FROM @t AS t
  JOIN cte AS c
    ON t.cntID = c.cntID
    AND CASE WHEN t.intCntId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = c.intCntId
    AND CASE WHEN t.conID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END = c.conID
  WHERE c.rn = 1
```

Comment: Please try on my given data it's not returning data for 922. This is my `trader_id` and I have to do this for at least more than one.

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine, let me test it in more detail with additional data. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (not sure the best way)

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties id,
                               cntID,
                               intCntId,
                               conID
        FROM   #mappingInfo
        ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(partition BY cntID ORDER BY id)) a
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id,
       a.cntID,
       a.intCntId,
       a.conID
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN conID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END conID_iden,
                       CASE WHEN intCntId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END intCntId_iden,
                       Row_number()OVER(partition BY cntID ORDER BY id) AS rn,*
                FROM   #mappingInfo) A
        WHERE  rn <> 1) A
       JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties CASE WHEN conID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS conID_iden,
                                    CASE WHEN intCntId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END intCntId_iden,*
             FROM   #mappingInfo
             ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(partition BY cntID ORDER BY id)) b
         ON a.conID_iden = b.conID_iden
            AND a.intCntId_iden = b.intCntId_iden
            AND a.cntID = b.cntID
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine, can I expect more simple & elegant way ? +1

Comment: Sorry @Prdp it's not working, if I add few more records for cndID, lets me add this in the question

Comment: Thanks, its working fine now. let me test it in more detail.